# How does the Chrome DevTools Protocol APIs work with Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

1. Are the [Chrome DevTools Protocol APIs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) open source? I'm trying to find out the source code to understand the working of some APIs in depth.
2. What exactly happens behind the scenes when we try to call those API using Puppeteer?
   This is how we use them -
   `const tree = await page._client.send('Page.getResourceTree');`
   I want to understand the how does this interface (page._client.send) work. Does it also make a request using the internet bandwidth or it works completely offline?

Comment: The source is linked on that page and you can find it by using google search, here it is: https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol

Comment: @wOxxOm I did search on Google before posting the question. I could find only the API interfaces in the repo, not the implementation.

Comment: It is recommended not to use the await page._client.send ('Page.getResourceTree'); since It is a private method (in javascript _method) nor is it documented